# Handle NSNotification while scrolling a inner UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotification

I need some `UIViewController`s that receive a `NSNotification` from the app delegate. It's like a timer, but every `UIViewController` handle your way. My problem is: when I interact with user interface, the `UIViewController` doesn't receive the notification, causing problems.

Here is my code in AppDelegate:

```
-(void)updateCounter:(NSTimer *)theTimer{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:TimeTickNotification object:nil];
}

//*called by some trigger in the app
-(void) startTimer{
    timer = [NSTimer
             scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5
             target:self
             selector:@selector(updateCounter:)
             userInfo:nil
             repeats:YES];
}
```

I am handling the notifications in each `UIViewController` like this:

```
-(void) updateGlobalTime:(NSNotification *) notification{
        totalTime = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:([ficha.tempoTotal floatValue] + STEP)];
}




-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(updateGlobalTime:)
                                                 name:TimeTickNotification
                                               object:nil];


}
```

What should I do to interact with UI and update it at same time? Maybe the NSNotification is not being thrown while user interacts with UI.

Comment: Are you posting your notification on the main thread?

Comment: @reecon Yes, It´s in main thread. Is it right?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use NSRunLoop, as following:

```
NSRunLoop *runloop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
timer = [NSTimer
             scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5
             target:self
             selector:@selector(updateCounter:)
             userInfo:nil
             repeats:YES];
[runloop addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
[runloop addTimer:timer forMode:UITrackingRunLoopMode];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you're updating any UI on the main thread.  If you want to update the UI to have the new `totalTime` in a label or something, make sure the `setText:` function is running on the main thread.  You can accomplish that with GCD, like this:

```
-(void) updateGlobalTime:(NSNotification *) notification{
        totalTime = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:([ficha.tempoTotal floatValue] + STEP)];

        // Update label on main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

             [label setText:totalTime];
        });
}
```

Comment: Alexander, the problem is: the method called from NSNotificationCenter isnt even called when I am scrolling a list inside the UIView. I tried your code and is not working.